# Kibana Search with NOT

Tags: kibana

Trying to do a Kibana search that includes some NOTs but getting results that include the NOTs so guessing my syntax is incorrect:

```
"chocolate" AND "milk" AND NOT "cow" AND NOT "tree"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add an '!' before each expression for NOT and you can use '( expression )' for more advanced expressions.

For your example this will work (it can be the same field): 
field1:chocolate AND field2:milk AND !(field3:cow AND field4:tree)

Answer (score 4):

"chocolate" AND "milk" NOT "cow"  NOT "tree"